# Is it safe to create a link to a socket file in /tmp?

Tags: linux, sockets

I'm a bit confused as to see that going from one Linux distribution to another, the package managers will sometimes configure processes to create the socket file either in `/tmp` or in `/var/run/%process%`, but I'm seeing it as a standard in open source projects that you configure your applications to refer to the socket in `/tmp`, as if to normalize the two options.

I too have chosen to distribute a project's configuration to refer to the socket in `/tmp`. Now I'd like to know, for the sake of not overriding the defaults, if I'd like to link a  socket from `/var/run` into `/tmp`, is there a safe way to do that?

I'm mostly asking this because I wouldn't like somebody to deal with spurious application errors because the `/tmp` directory got wiped clean and the socket link is no longer there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`/tmp` is not a "standard"<sup>0</sup> anymore for system daemons; the only program in wide use<sup>1</sup> that still puts sockets there is Xorg. All other daemons use `/run` or `/var/run` for this – precisely to avoid such problems as periodic /tmp cleaning or possible name collisions with user-created sockets.

There is no standard method of cleaning `/tmp` or excluding files from said cleanup.

---

<sup>0</sup> The [Filesystem Hierarchy Standard](http://www.pathname.com/fhs/) (FHS) has never defined `/tmp` for anything else but *temporary* files.

<sup>1</sup> That I know of.

Comment: I did some quick googling and found that [MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/problems-with-mysql-sock.html) and [MongoDB](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Command+Line+Parameters) will put the socket in `/tmp` by default. These are just small samples, but it goes to show that you can't specify a fixed path to the socket, which is why I'm assuming a lot of applications roll out with configurations that simply point to the socket in `/tmp` (say for those that expect to work with a MySQL socket). It's a bit of a hairy situation if there really is no safe way to link it!